# Google App Engine Golang connect to Cloud SQL Postgres unix dial no such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sql

Good day everyone, I am having trouble in connecting my golang application to a cloud sql postgres instance. I have just followed through their tutorial in Google Cloud Platform and sample code but it seems to be not working. I have just two files the app.yaml and main.go just to test the connection:

app.yaml

```
runtime: go api_version: go1 env: standard

env_variables:   CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME: bxustl2019proj:asia-east1:sqlstlbxu   CLOUDSQL_USER: ustldbbxu   CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD: bxuuserstldb   CLOUDSQL_DB: stlbxudbs

beta_settings:
      cloud_sql_instances: bxustl2019proj:asia-east1:sqlstlbxu

handlers:

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$   static_files: static/\1   upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)

- url: /.*   script: _go_app
```

main.go

```
package dptest

import (
    _"bytes"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

     _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var db *sql.DB

func init() {
    db = DB()

    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
}

// DB gets a connection to the database.
// This can panic for malformed database connection strings, invalid credentials, or non-existance database instance.
func DB() *sql.DB {
    /*
    var (
        connectionName = mustGetenv("CLOUDSQL_CONNECTION_NAME")
        user           = mustGetenv("CLOUDSQL_USER")
        dbname           = mustGetenv("CLOUDSQL_DB")
        password       = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD") // NOTE: password may be empty
        socket         = os.Getenv("CLOUDSQL_SOCKET_PREFIX")
    )

    //cloudsql is used on App Engine.
    if socket == "" {
        socket = "/cloudsql"
    }
    */
    // PostgreSQL Connection, uncomment to use.
    // connection string format: user=USER password=PASSWORD host=/cloudsql/PROJECT_ID:REGION_ID:INSTANCE_ID/[ dbname=DB_NAME]
    //dbURI := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s host=/cloudsql/%s database=%s", user, password, connectionName, dbname)
    dbURI := fmt.Sprintf("user=ustldbbxu password=bxuuserstldb host=/cloudsql/bxustl2019proj:asia-east1:sqlstlbxu/stlbxudbs")

    conn, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbURI)
    log.Printf("CONNECTION: %v", conn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("DB: %v", err))
    }

    rows, err := conn.Query("SELECT * FROM GAMES")
    log.Printf("ROW: %v", rows)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Could not query db: %v", err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    return conn
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")

    log.Printf("CONNECTION: %v", db)
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM GAMES")
    log.Printf("ROW: %v", rows)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Could not query db: %v", err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal Error", 500)
        return
    }
    defer rows.Close()
}

func mustGetenv(k string) string {
    v := os.Getenv(k)
    if v == "" {
        log.Panicf("%s environment variable not set.", k)
    }
    return v
}
```

I tried using go run . and goapp serve. I have tried adding appengine imports also but none seems to be working and it keeps on giving me the error:

> Could not query db: dial unix
>   /cloudsql/bxustl2019proj:asia-east1:sqlstlbxu/stlbxudbs/.s.PGSQL.5432:
>   connect: no such file or directory

Cloud SQL Admin is also enabled. I just commented out the env for easier run the error seems to be the same regardless of hardcoding the query path or importing from yaml.

I am hoping someone could help me on this.Thank you.

Comment: is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201556/failed-to-connect-to-database-setting-up-gcp-app-engine

Comment: thank you for the response, the error is really related..i have tried to follow through the documentation with the standard environment but still no avail..been stuck in this error for days now..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are connecting with App Engine (but you don't specify Standard or Flexible environments).

If you are on Standard, the unix socket is automatically available at `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>`.

If you are on Flexible, you need to specify the instance you want to connect to in the app.yaml, which will need create the unix socket at `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>`.

These unix sockets are only provided *in the runtimes themselves*. If you are running locally and want to connect, you will need to use the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) to create the unix socket at `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>` (or update your connection string to use Public IP and authenticate a different way).

Comment: thank you for your response, i have specified in the app.yaml the standard environment already..the code above runs in the cloud shell code editor but i can now access the database locally using proxy.. however, if i copy that code to the editor, same error appears even if i changed the connection strings..

Comment: The cloud shell is a different environment than running locally. You need to be running the proxy in your cloud shell to have access. It's worthing noting the cloud shell doesn't persist beyond the session - once you disconnect (or timeout) the proxy will by stopped and your `/cloudsql` folder will be removed. 

When I mentioned you hadn't specified Standard or Flex, I meant in your original post.

Comment: I do agree that cloud shell is different than running locally. I really thought I don't need to run the proxy in the cloud shell anymore since I have read the docs saying that apps in the same project are already authorized to access cloud sql instances. In case of deploying the app using go and cloud sql postgres, do you have suggestions regarding the connections strings?i have tried a lot of it but none seems to work and it gives me server error. thanks

Comment: Cloud Shell is provisioned VM in the cloud, which means that it's a different machine. Even if you start the proxy on your local machine, you'll have to start it up again in your cloud shell to connect from there.

For connection string your current example is missing dbname. What is included in the sample does work.

Comment: thank you so much for your inputs..it really helped me a lot..right now, my app is running in flexible environment..what i did is to start again from scratch then follow every step of the tutorial in the website specifically the flexible environment and viola..it works..thank you so much @kurtisvg

Comment: Don't forget to upvote or accept answers you found useful, as it helps other users more quickly determine if information is useful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone that is using this setup.
I've got a similar layout.

- GCR using Docker.
- Golang version 1.15
- ORM sqlboiler
- golang dbapi
- CloudSQL using postgresql with a public IP that you can only reach using the cloudsql proxy, but the connection between GCR -> CloudSQL was being rejected with
  models: unable to insert into user: dial tcp cloudsql-ip:5432: connect: connection timed out

## First step

When you deploy the instance

```
gcloud run deploy foo --add-cloudsql-instances the-literal-instance-connection-name --update-env-vars INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME="the-literal-instance-connection-name" --image your-image-name --region $REGION --project your-project-id --service-account=the-service-account-you-run-your-things --platform managed --no-allow-unauthenticated
```

The service account that is running that container has the IAM role Cloud SQL Client

### Toml format for sqlboiler

- host   = "/cloudsql/the-literal-instance-connection-name/"

### Golang lib/pq + golang db API connection using named unix sock

- host=/cloudsql/the-literal-instance-connection-name/

#### What is the-literal-instance-connection-name ?

Go to your CloudSQL instance and see the column Instance connection name and use that as a value.

#### Sources

- https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/tutorial-connect-run#prepare_the_code

The python example in the google cloud documentation

```
query_string = dict({"unix_sock": "/cloudsql/{}/.s.PGSQL.5432".format(connection_name)})
```

if you use a similar format in Golang, it won't work, after several trials and errors, I got the proper version working.

For example, adding .s.PGSQL.5432 in both connections ended up with an error like this

```
 unable to insert into user: dial unix /cloudsql/the-literal-instance-connection-name/.s.PGSQL.5432/.s.PGSQL.5432: connect: not a directory
```